# Urban Institute API max size

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to write a Python wrapper for accessing data from the Urban Institute datasets [link to the docs](https://educationdata.urban.org/documentation/) but the output caps at 3000 rows. The docs don't mention anything about authentication or how to bypass this limit. Below my code:

```
url = "https://educationdata.urban.org/api/v1/schools/ccd/directory/2014/?fips=26"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(response.read()), record_path=['results'])
```

This dataset caps at 3k, but if you paste directly to the browser, you can see that there are more than 3.5k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to retrieve each one of the pages of the API response, below the code that pulls all the pages.

```
import requests
url = "https://educationdata.urban.org/api/v1/schools/ccd/directory/2014/?fips=26"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
while data['next'] is not None:
    response = requests.get(data['next'])
```

Happy API scrapping!